# Revolution Slider fullwidth options to work on IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, slider, fullscreen

How to get Revolution Slider fullwidth options, like images to work on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your IE8 stylesheet

```
    .ieeightfallbackimage{ width:auto !important; height:auto !important; min-width:100% !important; min-height:100% !important;}
```